# How to use hook_webform_submission_presave

Tags: webforms

In webform 7.x-4.10 I created a module like this:

```
function webform_presave_webform_submission_presave($node, &$submission) {
  if ($webform->nid == 28) {
    $component_id = 1;
    $submission->data[$component_id]['value'][0] = 'Yes';
  }
}
```

My webform with nid 28 has only one field, a texfield with a default value to "No".

When the webform is submitted, the value of the field is not change...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: there is a typo in the code, it is not "if($webform->nid == 28)" it is "if($submission->nid == 28)" but the problem is the same, it's not working ^^

Comment: In fact after reading webform.api.php in the webform directory, the ['value'] in "$submission->data[$component_id]['value'][0]" has nothing to do there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice the value on which you check in the if.

the correct code is:

```
function webform_presave_webform_submission_presave($node, &$submission) {
  if ($submission->nid == 28) {
    $component_id = 1;
    $submission->data[$component_id][0] = 'Yes';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why *the value of the field does not change* (assuming the name of your module == webform_presave) is due to the fact that the if statement fails because **$webform** is not defined. Use this instead:

```
function webform_presave_webform_submission_presave($node, &$submission) {
  if ($node->nid == 28) {
    $component_id = 1;
    $submission->data[$component_id]['value'][0] = 'Yes';
  }
}
```

See hook_webform_submission_presave() in webform.api.php.